# Angular 2 binding to form select value

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to control the color of an element pending user selection of a form select element. Currently I can only get it working statically.

`selectedEventGroup: string[]`; //this grabs the users selection in the form select dropdown.

`color: string = SchedulingMatrix.selectedEventGroup.value;` //This doesnt work returns error. "selectedEventGroup does not exist on typeof SchedulingMatrix which might be another issue all by itself.

`color: string = "green";` //This works but is static

my select component`<p-dropdown [options]="eventGroup" [(value)]="eventGroup" style="width: 180px;"></p-dropdown>`

```
import....

@Component({
  ...
})
export class SchedulingMatrix implements OnInit {

  events: any[];

  event: MyEvent;

  dialogVisible: boolean = false;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {

    this.eventGroup = [];
    this.eventGroup.push({
      label: 'Select Group',
      value: '#fff'
    });
    this.eventGroup.push({
      label: 'group 1',
      value: '#ccc'
    });
    this.eventGroup.push({
      label: 'group 2',
      value: '#ddd'
    });
    this.eventGroup.push({
      label: 'group 3',
      value: '#eee'
    });

  }

  eventGroup: SelectItem[];
  selectedEventGroup: string[]; //this grabs the users selection in the select dropdown.

}

export class MyEvent {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  start: string;
  end: string;
  color: string = "green"; //This works but is static
  //color: string = SchedulingMatrix.selectedEventGroup.value;  //Not sure what to use here to  hook up to the the users selection in the eventGroup
  allDay: boolean = true;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Why is `selectedEventGroup` an array?

Comment: //color: string = SchedulingMatrix.selectedEventGroup.value;  //Not working

Comment: What is `<p-dropdown>`?

Comment: Its a component from the primeNG library.http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
<select *ngIf="eventGroup" [(ngModel)]="selectedObject">
  <option *ngFor="let x of objectList" [ngValue]="x">
       {{...}}
  </option>
</select>
```

where selectedObject is any object
and try this [ngValue] instead [(value)]="eventGroup"